# ValueAnimator Helper Class

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am a beginner in Android development.

Coming from iOS background I tend to use animations on Views

to animate a View in Android. I have found out to do it in a "normal" way

For example to animate alpha value of a view

```
valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 100);

valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            viewToAnimate.alpha(value);
        }
    });

valueAnimator.setDuration(10000);
valueAnimator.start();
```

I am wondering if there is an easy way. Perhaps create a "Helper" class to animate an objects alpha value. Where we can pass in the View to animate and have it animated.

Something like `AnimationHelper.animateAlpha(viewToAnimate, OF_VALUE, TO_VALUE, DURATION);`

I am sorry to ask this question. Since my Java knowledge is rusty, I am wondering if there is any kind folks out there who is willing to help out.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
viewToAnimate.animate().alpha(TO_VALUE).setDuration(DURATION);
```

or this:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToAnimate, "alpha", FROM_VALUE, TO_VALUE);
anim.setDuration(DURATION);
anim.start();
```

Comment: Thanks, btw is there any onComplete on liner method we can use on the `viewToAnimate.animate().alpha(TO_VALUE).setDuration(DURATION);` ?